# How is pass by reference different from static

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I was doing a leetcode question where I was using a `static index` which I iterated every time the function called itself. When I ran it on VSCode, it was giving me the desired output but when I submitted it to leetcode, it was showing me out of range value. I did some trial and error and I found out that if I declare `index` in function as pass by reference, the solution is accepted. It got me thinking about what difference could this change in code make internally. Below is my function code.

```cpp
    TreeNode* helper(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder,int start,int end,int &index){
        if(start>end) return NULL;
        // static int index = 0; //It was declared here prior to moving it above in function
        int curr = preorder.at(index);
        TreeNode *node = new TreeNode(curr);
        index++;
        if(start==end) return node;
        int pos = search(inorder,curr,start,end);
        node->left = helper(preorder,inorder,start,pos-1,index);
        node->right = helper(preorder,inorder,pos+1,end,index);
        return node;
    }
```

(The code is about constructing a binary tree from preOrder and inOrder just in case someone is wondering).

Answer (score 0):

The main différence is that `static` local variables will be initialized only once. The first time the function runs.

You don't show the use case and how you passed and init'ed index. But that's the most likely reason. The static index probably simply retained the value from previous run.

Other differences:

There is a single static instance of the index var. If you pass something by reference, you can pass different ones.

The value passed by reference can be modified elsewhere. The static local var can only be modified in that function.

Comment: It was meant to hold the previous value of the function. Actually, it was just a pointer kinda thing so that I can update the curr value from the preOrder array. So initially i=0 and we inserted 1st value of preOrder. After that, we increment i and then curr must have 2nd value. It was running good in my compiler and in leetcode run code section too but gave me out of bound error while submitting the code